Change color/style of vertical line between block start-end in algorithm2e
How can I change the line color (and for that matter style, such as line width, dashed, double lines) of the vertical lines between block start-end keywords in the algorithm2e package? Thanks in advance!
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \If{test}{
        \For{i = 1}{
            Do something\;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}

Desired result:


Quick hack to change the colour:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vsline}[1]{%    no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
  \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
  \algocf@bblockcode%
  \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
  \hbox{\textcolor{green!80!black}{\vrule}%               the vertical rule
    \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
      \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal #1}}}% inside the block
  \algocf@pop{\skiprule}% restore indentation
  \algocf@eblockcode%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \If{test}{
        \For{i = 1}{
            Do something\;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}



As far as my knowledge, these options are not provided in the package, hope you can contact the package maintainer for these options. For your requirement, have slightly modify the existing tag \algocf@Vsline, and the MWE is:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vsline}[1]{%    no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
  \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
  \algocf@bblockcode%
  \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
  \hbox{\color{cyan}\hskip-5pt\vrule \@width5pt\color{black}%  Please keep the rule thickness and hskip value are same    
    \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
      \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal #1}}}% inside the block
  \algocf@pop{\skiprule}% restore indentation
  \algocf@eblockcode%
}
\makeatother

\begin{algorithm}
    \If{test}{
        \For{i = 1}{
            Do something\;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}

Output

